# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'

Tags: syntax

Slightly confused about why I'm getting this error;

```
select * 
from #test1
where basepolicystartdate < '20160701' 
  and basepolicyenddate is not null
  and renewaldate is not null
where basepolicyid = 5294
```

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'

If anyone can point me in the right direction.

Using SQL Server Management Studio 2017

Comment: `WHERE basepolicyid = 5294` did you mean to have another `and` ?

Comment: `WHERE basepolicyid = 5294` did you actually include this with your query?

Comment: Yes, well I think so. Been handed this and the person has left, figuring out his stuff is making me lose my hair!

Comment: I'd go out on a limb, and guess that the `where basepolicyid = 5294` was used for debugging, and the original author of the SQL accidentally left that in. I'm not suggesting that you blindly remove it without understanding what the query is meant to do, but it's likely not meant to be there.

Comment: Thank you, soon as I took it out and selected the bit I wanted to test run it was ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE basepolicyid = 5294
```

You already have a WHERE clause in your query, did you mean to add another 'AND'?

EDIT: Added formatting to make it easier to read.

Comment: Fair enough, Thanks for letting me know, I'm kind of new to replying on StackOverflow.